# Location of current Firefox zoom level

Tags: firefox, zoom

Where can the current zoom level be observed in Firefox? For instance, if the current zoom level is 155%, where can 155% be observed?

Assume:

1. not all toolbars, sidebars, etc. are active (for example, a particular toolbar may need to be activated in order to display the zoom level)
2. if it matters, Firefox 8.0.1.
3. [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) is installed. It takes up space at the bottom of most (but not all pages) as it usually blocks some JavaScript. However the zoom level does not appear on [this page](http://drmortensen.eu/) where nothing is blocked.

Answer (score 6):

I checked my Firefox (10.0.1) and there is only 1 item in the "customize toolbar" window related to zooming, which is `+ / - zoom controls`. When I add it, it only shows the `+ / -` buttons, and not the zoom level.

Then I checked for possible addons that may be of help. [Default FullZoom Level](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/default-fullzoom-level/) seems promising. It indicates zoom level in statusbar.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Zoom Page](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/zoom-page/) add-on to get an indicator on the panel.

[image]